# Why does Chrome mark a "204 No Content" response red?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, http-status-code-204

I'm very confused by chrome,  it marks a "204 No Content" response red in the request list but at the same time has a green point for the "Status Code". I'm sure 204 isn't an error so what happens here?

I've created a new script to ensure that there is nothing else going on:

```
<?php

http_response_code(204);
```

And the developer tools look like this:

[image]

I'm using chrome 34.0.1847.116 m, it's not red in Firefox by the way.

Comment: I'm using google chrome 39.0.2171.95 m and I'm not getting the red in the listing when I run above PHP script on my local web server. I imagine that someone must have realized that the red in this case was a mistake and corrected it.  I still get the red in the listing for a 404 status message as one would expect.

Comment: Im using version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (arm64) and it is throwing errors for 204 No Content. Which is strange because this is a response that indicates a "successful" HTTP/2 response.